# Specifying some template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I want to write an own Vector-class and a function which calculates the cross product.

My Vector-class has the

```
template<class T, int dim, bool isRowVector>
```

T is the type of the entries, dim the dimension and isRowVector specifies whether the vector is a row or a column vector.

I overloaded some operators of Vector, particularly <<:

```
template <class T, int dim, bool isRowVec>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Vector<T, dim, isRowVec>& vec) // <<
{
    os << "[" << vec[0];

    for(typename std::vector<T>::iterator it = vec.begin()+1; it != vec.end(); it++) {
        os << "," << *it;
    }

    os << "]";

    if(!isRowVec) { os << "^T"; }

    return os;
}
```

Now the function crossProduct should only apply on Vectors with dim = 3. So I specified the function like this:

```
template <class T, bool isRowVec>
Vector<T, 3, isRowVec> crossProduct (Vector<T, 3, isRowVec> a, Vector<T, 3, isRowVec> b) {
    T arr[3] = { a[1]*b[2]-a[2]*b[1], a[2]*b[0]-a[0]*b[2], a[0]*b[1]-a[1]*b[0] };
    Vector<T, 3, isRowVec> newVec(arr);
    return newVec;
}
```

omitting the dim parameter in the function template, since it does not have to be guessed or stated.

This doesn't seem to be a problem, since

```
Vector<float,3,true> a = crossProduct(f,g);
```

does not create a compile-error, where f and g are both

```
Vector<float,3,true>
```

But when I try to call

```
std::cout << crossProduct(f, g) << std::endl;
```

I get

```
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'Vector<float, 3, true>')
  std::cout << crossProduct(f, g) << std::endl;
            ^
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::cout << crossProduct(f, g) << std::endl;
             |
             |
             +------Creates a temporary object (rvalue)
```

rvalues cannot bind to non-const references, so use `const` reference instead

```
template <class T, int dim, bool isRowVec>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Vector<T, dim, isRowVec>& vec) 
//                                         ~~~~~
{
   // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `operator <<` you need `const & vec` rather than `& vec`.

You can't pass a temporary to a non-const reference, so you can't pass the result of the `crossProduct` call.